# C# outputting csv data on separate lines in a rich text box

Tags: c#, csv

Hi I'm new to c# and have encountered an issue. I'm trying to make a small piece of code that reads the data from a CSV file and output each piece of data on a separate line.

My issue is that even though the data is outputted in the text box, the data isn't put on separate lines (ideally I would then be able to store each line in their own variable or string, but thats for another day)

This is the code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        char[] stringsplit = { ' ', ',' };


        string doc = File.ReadAllText("FILE NAME HERE");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(doc);
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\n");

        string[] doc_output = doc.Split(stringsplit);


        string doc2 = "", doc_ouput;

        richTextBox1.AppendText(doc2);

        foreach (string s in doc_output)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(s);
        }
    }
```

And this is what is outputted:

Reference,Details,Price
F10111,100mm tk coloured facing brickwork,56.25

F10112,100mm Engineering brickwork,56.25

ReferenceDetailsPrice

F10111100mmtkcolouredfacingbrickwork56.25

F10112100mmEngineeringbrickwork56.25

My issue is that the second set of the data removes the comments but doesn't insert new lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just concatenate a new line character at the end of each line you add to the textbox:

```
foreach (string s in doc_output)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! problem solved, thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Enviroment.NewLine`;

Or `rtb.AppendText(@"\line")`;